# TextView text wrap and width

Tags: android, textview

The idea is to have TextView and ImageButton to the right of it. TextView is multiline, both are centered verically (depends on who is higher). All goes well until some long texts are moved to the next line, leaving huge hole between (visible) right edge of TextView. It works good, but looks not. How can you suggest to do this?

Too make it more clear: the button should be **to the right visible edge of TextView, not to the right of parent**. The problem is to understand TextView's visible width, I mean the width of it's content.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/proxima_nova_regular"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Some title"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:fontFamily="@font/proxima_nova_regular"
            android:paddingEnd="40dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            tools:text="aaaaaaaa bbbbb ddddddddddddddddd eeee"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="-40dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/name"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/standard_content_description"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:padding="4dp"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`

```
    <ImageButton
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/name"
        android:clickable="true"  
     android:contentDescription="@string/standard_content_description"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:padding="4dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"/>
```

Comment: No, the button should be to the right visible edge of TextView, not to the right of parent.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the image at the end of screen to make it more stable UI. Otherwise it's look odd due to different positions of Image. To do so add these to your code:

add   `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`

and romove             `android:layout_toEndOf="@id/name"`

Comment: No, the button should be to the right visible edge of TextView, not to the right of parent.

Answer (score 0):

First, do as others have suggested and set attribute for the ImageButton 
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

Second, get rid of the padding end on the textView. All that is doing for you is killing the amount of space available for text.

Third, add an attribute to your TextView to align to start of the image.
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn"

Your code should look something like this:

```
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn"
    tools:text="aaaaaaaa bbbbb dddddddd haveeverythinginlinefortheotherpeopletoseewhatyouhavedoneinthemaintextview"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:padding="4dp"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"/>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OYO3.png)Now you can have the text wrap that you want. However, Android TextView does not have an attribute that allows for hyphens and cannot decide where to break a long word or set of letters. Therefore, the textView will break when it is convenient for it to do so, like after a space in the text. Otherwise, it will allow text to fill the container until the end of a line and continue on the next line.

Comment: The button should be to the right visible edge of TextView, not to the right of parent. The problem is to understand TextView's visible width, I mean the width of it's content.

Comment: With the changes I suggested, the button will stay to the right side of the layout and not move as the wrap_content of the text gets bigger or smaller. As I mentioned before "TextView does not have an attribute that allows for hyphens and cannot decide where to break a long word or set of letters. Therefore, the textView will break when it is convenient for it to do so". You cannot control the "text wrap" like you can in MS Word.  Of course you can still align the button to the textView and it will move based on how much text is available.

Answer (score -1):

```
Please add code like below.
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/from1"
                android:maxLength="8"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:hint="55"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/textlayout"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/from1"
                android:gravity="center"                
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/start_btn"
                android:layout_height="35dp" />
       </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The button should be to the right visible edge of TextView, not to the right of parent. TextView should support multiline.